# Monitoring Glassfish 4 on Docker with JVisualVM

Tags: java, glassfish, docker, jvisualvm

I'm not able to connect JVisualVM to Glassfish running on Docker. I'm using the [glassfish nightly image](https://hub.docker.com/r/glassfish/nightly/) and I'm exposing port 8686. On Startup Glassfish is logging the following:

```
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://55bbdd404578:8686/jndi/rmi://55bbdd404578:8686/jmxrmi
```

The IP of my docker host is 192.168.99.100 and I can connect via telnet on port 8686.

The Service URL I'm using is `service:jmx:rmi://192.168.99.100:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.99.100:8686/jmxrmi` and I'm passing the security credentials but can't connect. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Struggled with the same issue.

Add following to server-config –> jvm-settings –> JVM option

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port='your JMX port'
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname='IP of you docker host'
```

and simply do the rest in the same way as before.

When U look at server.log U'll notice that JMX service is exposed as:

```
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://e15295161718:40086/jndi/rmi://e15295161718:40086/jmxrmi
```

and problably these configuration entries change **e15295161718** to **IP** and JVisualVM can connect. From Ur host's perspective **e15295161718** is rubbish to JVisualVM.

Answer (score 0):

Port 8686 is not exposed by Docker file, therefore
You need to use --publish 8686:8686 with docker run command to make that port exposed to the host computer. See docker help run for mire details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I wrote in the question: I am exposing port 8686 and I can connect via telnet so I'm pretty sure the port is open.